# Problemas para obtener el valor de una Promiesa async await "Promise { <pending> }"

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

Estoy sacándome algunas dudas que tengo con Javascript y una de esta es la siguiente:
quiero obtener lo que retorna una promesa async await , pero no lo quiero hacer utilizando el .then(), si no que solo quiero utilizar el async await, estuve intentando y solo obtengo como retorno el objeto promise con sus propiedades:

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseValue]]: valordeloqueretorna
```

Si bien ya se que una promesa async await siempre retorna un promise yo solo necesito su promisevalue no el objeto promesa

dejo el codigo:

```
 async function PromiseTesting (){
  const api = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/");
  var data = await api.json();
  var dataname =  data.name;
  return dataname;

}


var datos = PromiseTesting();
console.log(datos);
```

Comment: La promesa es asíncrona, y para ello necesitas manejar la promesa manualmente. Ya intente esto `datos.then((res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: no se puede manejar de otra manera que no sea utilizando el .then()?? , pensé que con async await habria otra forma de manejarla pero al parecer no , gracias!!

Comment: El problema con tu código es que PromiseTesting es async, por lo tanto tambien retorna una promesa... A la cual también le debes hacer `await` antes de hacer el `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

Como bien señala [@Pipe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2743/pipe) en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455932/problemas-para-obtener-el-valor-de-una-promiesa-async-await-promise-pending#comment812122_455932), la función `PromiseTesting` es `async`, es decir, retorna una `Promise`.

#### Solución 1

Podes leer los datos usando el método [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) propio de las [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
async function PromiseTesting() {
  const api = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/");
  var data = await api.json();
  var dataname = data.name;
  return dataname;

}

PromiseTesting()
  .then(datos => console.log(datos));
```

---

#### Solución 2

Usando `async/await` (*en este ejemplo usa una [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE)*)

```js
(async function() {
  async function PromiseTesting() {
    const api = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/");
    var data = await api.json();
    var dataname = data.name;
    return dataname;

  }
  var datos = await PromiseTesting();
  console.log(datos);
})();
```